# ADF Table with detailStamp set height in pixels not with autoHeightRows attribute

Tags: oracle-adf

**autoHeightRows** works with rows, but how can you set the height in **pixels**, so that a scroll bar appears ?

I need this because my table has **detailStamp** of **different heights**.

The solution of putting the table inside a panel and set there the height isn't good because the Header must be fixed, I want to scroll only the content of the table.